# Fast/Area optimised sorting in hardware (fpga)

Tags: sorting, vhdl, fpga

I'm trying to sort an array of 8bit numbers using vhdl.
I'm trying to find out a method which optimise delay and another which would use less hardware.

The size of the array is fixed. But I'm also interested to extend the functionality to variable lengths.
I've come across 3 algorithms so far:

1. Bathcher Parallel
2. Method Green Sort
3. Van Vorris Sort

Which of these will do the best job? Are there any other methods I should be looking at?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read about this in a book by Knuth and according to that book, the Batcher's parallel merge sort is the fastest algorithm and also the most hardware efficient.

Comment: Same book referred on the wikipedia page : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batcher_odd%E2%80%93even_mergesort

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of research articles in the matter. You could try to search the web for it. I did a search for "Sorting Networks" and came up with a lot of comparisons of different algorithms and how well they fitted into an FPGA.

The algorithm you choose will greatly depend on which parameter is most important to optimize for, i.e. latency, area, etc. Another important factor is where the values are stored at the beginning and end of the sort. If they are stored in registers, all might be accessed at once, but if you have to read them from a memory with a limited width, you should consider that in your implementation as well, because then you will have to sort values in a stream, and rearrange that stream before saving it back to memory.

Personally, I'd consider something time-constant like merge-sort, which has a constant time to sort, so you could easily schedule the sort for a fixed size array. I'm however not sure how well this scales or works with arbitrary sized arrays. You'd probably have to set an upper limit on array size, and also this approach works best if all data is stored in registers.